# setting a cookie using php for dropdown menu in html page

Tags: php, html, cookies

i want to set a cookie for dropdown menu in the html form ,when refresh the page i should get the value that is  stored in the cookie in my drop down box.
I have written code for input box as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{

var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
</script>

<input name="order_num" type="text" size="10" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["order_num"])) echo $_COOKIE["order_num"];?>" onblur="setCookie(this.name,this.value,60*60*2)" />
```

In the similar way i want to write the cookie for dropdown box.the code for drop down menu is 
follows:

```
<select name="quality" onChange="setCookie('quality',this.value,60*60*2)" selected="" >
<option >Select One</option>  
<option value="good" selected="good">Good</option>
<option value="ok" selected="ok">A bit low but we can use it</option>
...

</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="proceed_opt[]" value="I will upload new Image" onblur="setCookie(this.name,this.value,60*60*2);>
         Insert Option &quot;I will upload new Image&quot;</td></tr>


         <input type="checkbox" name="proceed_opt[]" value="I approve this sample for a Night Light" onblur="setCookie(this.name,this.value,60*60*2);>
         Insert Option &quot;<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">I approve this sample for a Night Light</font>&quot;
```

any one help me to set the cookie....

Comment: no...  In the javascript i have written setcookie() function.

Comment: Ok. What's the problem with this code?

Comment: im getting the output for input text field as i expected i.e after refreshing the page ,the value i entered is still there in text field but when i refresh the page the value selected from the drop down menu is not shown,even though cookie is set.

Comment: any one help me, to sort out this ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the cookie value equals the select item. If so, give the item the HTML `selected` attribute.

```
$choices = array(
  'good' => 'Good',
  'ok'   => 'A bit low but we can use it'
);

<select name="quality" onChange="setCookie('quality', this.value, 60*60*2)">
  <option>Select One</option>

  <?php foreach ($choices as $value=>$select): ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $value ?>"
      <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["quality"]) && $_COOKIE["quality"] == $value): ?>
        selected="selected"
      <?php endif; ?>
    >
      <?php echo $select ?>
    </option>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

</select>
```

This code may need some modification because I didn't test it. But the main idea is there.

---

Edit: Example for checkboxes:

```
$choices = array(
  'good' => 'Good',
  'ok'   => 'A bit low but we can use it'
);

<?php foreach ($choices as $value=>$choice): ?>

  <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $value ?>"
    onclick="setCookie('checkbox', this.value, 60*60*2)"
    <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["checkbox"]) && $_COOKIE["checkbox"] == $value): ?>
      checked="checked"
    <?php endif; ?>
  >
  <?php echo $select ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The problem with this code is that it won't work if the user doesn't click the check box, but choose it using the keyboard for example.

Comment: thank you very much,this one solved my problem for dropdown menu.can u  please tell me how can i set cookie in the similar way for check boxes.the code for check box is above in my code.

Comment: Do it the same way, but use `checked="checked"` instead of `selected="selected"`. :)

Comment: I place checked="checked" but its not working..in the case my check boxes.can u show me how can i do that

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="proceed_opt[]" value="I_will_upload_new_Image" <?php if( isset($_COOKIE["I_will_upload_new_Image"]) && $_COOKIE["I_will_upload_new_Image"] == I_will_upload_new_Image) echo "checked='checked'";?> onclick="setCookie('checkbox',this.value,60*60*2)";>

Comment: i change the code for check box as above.but its not effected when i refresh the page.can u tell me the modifications in my code  without using foreach loop

Comment: `onclick="setCookie('checkbox',this.value,60*60*2)"` should be `onclick="setCookie('I_will_upload_new_Image',this.value,60*60*2)"`.